# What's the proper way: Forever Lucky, or Lucky Forever?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, adjectives

The title says it all, what's the proper way to say it?

Also, could you please explain me the why one is the right form, and the other is the wrong form?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's a proper form of your question: Moreover, Could you explain the reason that the first one is correct but the other one is not? or Moreover, Could you explain why the first one is correct but the other one is not? P.S: explain me is wrong, we don't have this form, for instance you can use this format: explain something to somebody.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and should have been posted as a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**

One reflects the past; one is predicting the future.

**Long Version**

The words "Forever Lucky" indicate a past tense in which it is assumed that the lucky or
fortuitous events have occurred and may occur in the present and *possibly* beyond.

> As I flipped over the two Aces my opponent stared at me in shock and spat in my direction. "As always Smith, forever lucky.  Every damn time."

However the words "Lucky forever" serve as a promise or statement regarding a neverending run of luck not just based on the past but also highly likely to be true in the future.

> I was born to wealthy parents who could afford to send me to the best schools in the United States.  It was after I graduated and subsequently took a seat at my father's company I realised; I was due to be lucky forever."